# facebook api return nothing but with me I have the data

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

I make a Facebook app, now we change it from server and I run again the codes to test it, and I found that it works perfectly except for one FQL. I get the user info with ->(/me)

The FLQ works (I tested with Facebook tools). My connection and scope its correct. any idea?

I leave you my fql

```
$scope = 'email,read_stream';
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
     'appId'  => $app_id,
     'secret' => $app_secret,
));

// Get the current user
$user = $facebook->getUser();
    $fql    =   "SELECT type, source_id, share_count, likes, permalink, description, post_id, message, target_id, created_time, attachment
                FROM stream 
                WHERE source_id =  me()  and type in (46, 80)
                order by created_time desc
                LIMIT 500";
    $param  =   array(
     'method'    => 'fql.query',
     'query'     => $fql,
     'callback'  => ''
    );

    $fqlResult  =  $facebook->api($param);
    print_r($fqlResult);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my problem,

the code works, but I was asking for two specific types.
  and type in (46, 80)

When I remove it it appear all the stream :)

Thanks to everyone

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't use FQL personally as there's a reason they depreciate the old API's, but to access feed data of the user you need to have granted access from the API for your application, it should handle access_tokens automatically but when your user logs in with your website you want to be using

```
$params = array(
  'scope' => 'read_stream, friends_likes',
   // Access to feed data (read_stream) and whatever else you need
  'redirect_uri' => 'https://www.myapp.com/post_login_page'
);

$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
```

Then you can access all the information you want with the api query:

```
$facebook->api('/me?fields=feed.fields(source,id,shares,likes,link,description,message,created_time)', 'GET');
```

I highly recommend using the [Facebook Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET) to test API queries and retrieve all the information you need

Hope that helps mate!

Answer (score 1):

In the parameter array, add one more parameter : access_token and give it the valid access token value

Comment: Hi @Shadowfax, thanks, but two things. 1-. Why this works with the exact same code "SELECT friend_count FROM user WHERE uid = me()" and two how can i get the access token?

Comment: doesn't works

$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
 
 //Exportamos todos los datos
 $fql    =   "SELECT type, source_id, share_count, likes, permalink, description, post_id, message, target_id, created_time, attachment
    FROM stream 
    WHERE source_id =  me()  and type in (46, 80)
    order by created_time desc
    LIMIT 500";
 $param  =   array(
  'method'    => 'fql.query',
  'query'     => $fql,
  'callback'  => '',
  'access_token' => $access_token
 );